# Returning a multilevel resultset in Java

Tags: java, sql

For REST API's, I send the filter criteria and get back a JSON array (just like everyone else does it).

In my Java servlet, I use SQL statements such as:

```
String sql = 
  "select im.InvoiceDate, s.StoreId, s.StoreName, id.ItemId, id.Quantity " +
  "from InvoiceMaster as im " +
  "left join InvoiceDetail as id on id.InvoiceId = im.InvoiceId " +
  "left join Stores as s on s.StoreId = im.StoreId ";
rs = connection.executeQuery(sql);
```

Next, I have a generic function that is similar to https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc-convert-resultset-to-json which converts all columns as JSON attributes and rows as objects into one array. Something like:

```
JSONObject jo = ConvertRSToJSON(rs);
Result:
{
  "selectTime": 500,
  [
    {
       "InvoiceDate": "2023-01-01",
       "StoreId": 55,
       "StoreName": "Acme",
       "ItemId": 77,
       "Quantity": 10
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

In the above, there's a lot of duplication, for an invoice with 10 items, all the other attributes are appearing redundantly.

I was wondering if I can get a multilevel resultset so the final object would be:

```
{
  "selectTime": 500,
  [
    {
       "InvoiceDate": "2023-01-01",
       "Store": [
         {
           "StoreId": 55,
           "StoreName": "Acme"
         }
       ],
       "InvoiceDetails": [
         {
           "ItemId": 5,
           "Quantity": 15
         },
         {
           "ItemId": 77,
           "Quantity": 10
         }
         ...
       ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I could remove the JOIN's, select the main table, iterate the results, run queries for the secondary tables, convert each resultset to JSON and then combine them into one JSONArray, but that's too much manual change and would be slower with so many executeQuery statements running in loops.

*P.S: Yes, I know the JSON's above are not well-formed as they are for explanation only.*

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what your problem is. Once you have the query output in "flat form", just group it according to the criteria you want and only then serialize the data in json.

Comment: I don't quite follow. How would I group it?

Comment: as you wish, for example like this https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector

Comment: Thanks. I am reading it right now. I'll see if it works for Java 1.6. The client's app that I maintain is quite old and they don't want to pay for the effort of moving up to a new platform.

Comment: No, it's the stream api. But anyway, the implementation is trivial - You use Map<K, List<T>> to group your data with a simple loop (K is the invoice key/date and T is sales by invoice). Then simply serialize the map